# What is a raptor engine manifold and what's happening in these tweeted pics?

Tags: spacex, engines, identify-this-object, raptor

When I think of the words "engine manifold" I think of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=exhaust+manifold&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X).

I saw [this tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1096722535217917952) by Elon Musk which shows the image below, and then there is a reply image with a checkerboard pattern behind part of the manifold.

**Question:** What are we looking at? Is this cooling metal, or is it still in the mold? What is that checkerboard pattern in the 2nd image? What part of the engine is this; what items does it connect?

[image]

Reply [tweet](https://twitter.com/ultih_/status/1096760190106505219)

[image]

Comment: A Minecraft joke on the 2nd one?

Comment: @OrganicMarble dunno, I'm illiterate in that area

Comment: Yeah, the second pic is not from Musk; it's Minecraft merch photoshopped in, visually joking that the first pic is reminiscent of a blacksmith's forge in operation.

Comment: Dunno anything about metal forging, but I think that's the manifold still in the mold (or the mold burning away?). The "manifold" on an F-1 is where exhaust from the gas generator is returned to the nozzle, but Raptor is full-flow staged combustion so I guess this would be the plumbing that returns the post-turbopump exhaust to the primary combustion chamber.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/ThinkGeek-Minecraft-Sword-Porkchop-Adventure/dp/B0756G26QW/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1550796963&sr=8-14&keywords=minecraft+sword

Comment: @RussellBorogove to the left of the manifold in the altered image, "UltiH" is "written" on the wall, any thoughts?

Comment: @uhoh it's the name of the twitter account that tweeted the Minecraft photo.

Comment: On the SSME the "hot gas manifold" took the hot gas from the outlet of the preburners/turbines and piped it to the main combustion chamber.  page # 25 in this: http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf

Comment: @OrganicMarble that's a really beautiful presentation, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accompanying text on Twitter:

> SpaceX foundry casting Raptor engine manifold out of Inconel

So what you're seeing here is a rough casting.

Usually, metal is cast in a sand mold, and left in the mold until it's cooled off. The mold is a bunch of (special-formula) sand in a box, (usually rectangular).

In this case the mold has been removed while the casting is still glowing red.

The shape of the part is difficult to make out because there is a lot of excess material which will be milled off later.